# Mathematical Logic Problem?

Tags: logic

I'm trying to solve this mathematical logic problem, can someone please at least give me a tip on how to approach this problem?

> The square of any positive real number is a positive real number.
>
> Write down the,
>
> 1. statement in symbolic form
> 2. the converse of the statement in symbolic form
> 3. the negation of the statement in symbolic form and sentence form

Thank you.

Comment: What symbols do you have in mind? You have done a good enough job using English language "symbols."

Comment: @user2943324 The usual symbols used in mathematical logic, $\land \lor \lnot $ etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Try thinking of the given sentence as:

> For any $x$, if $x$ is a positive real number, then $x^2$ is a positive real number.

**Hint 2:** Suppose that we have a statement of the form:
$$
\text{If $p$ is true, then $q$ is true.}\tag{1}
$$
Then the **converse** of $(1)$ is of the form:
$$
\text{If $q$ is true, then $p$ is true.}
$$
Furthermore, the **negation** of $(1)$ is of the form:
$$
\text{$p$ is true but $q$ is false.}
$$
**Hint 3:** Recall that negations of universally quantified predicates turn into existentially quantified (negated) predicates. More precisely:
$$
\neg[\forall x,~ P(x)] \qquad\text{is equivalent to}\qquad \exists x ~~\neg P(x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you define $P(x)$ (or whatever form you use) to mean "$x$ is a positive real number", the first becomes $P(x) \implies P(x^2)$  How do you write the converse of an implication?  To write the negation, you can just precede it by $\lnot$, but you may be expected to turn it into a conjuction.  How can an implication be false?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was having trouble preparing the initial statement. I can manage the rest.

Answer (score 1):

First translate the sentence to 'first order English' language:

> - For all positive real number, its square is positive.
> - For all real number $x$, if $x$ is positive, then $x^2$ is positive.